# What's the best algorithm of these 2 (in Java) to delete certain values in a list?

Tags: java, complexity-theory

What's the best algorithm of these 2 (in Java) to delete certain values in a list?
1: using an arraylist
2: using a linkedlist

```
for (int i = arraylist.size()-1; i >= 0; i--) {
        if(arraylist.get(i).getValue() < 20)
            list.remove(i);
    }
```

or

```
for (int i = linkedlist.size()-1; i >= 0; i--) {
        if(linkedlist.get(i).getValue() < 20)
            list.remove(i);
    }
```

Also, what's the complexity of these 2 algorithms? (if in for loop)?
I think it's O(n), but I am not sure...

Comment: You will have _O(n)_ in the first algorithm and _O(n)_ in the second algorithm, unless you have to sort the list first which gives you an added _O(nlogn)_.

Comment: Oh God... you just completely changed the meaning of your question -.-

Comment: @Johan: You cannot edit the question like you have when answers have already been provided for your initial question. Either clearly state your question in the first place or indicate that it has been edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### `LinkedList`

You should *never, ever* iterate over a linked list by indexing into it. Indexing into a linked list is an `O(n)` operation. Here's a break-down:

1. You iterate over the size of the list: `n` steps => `O(n)` operation.
2. You index into it to get a stored value: `O(n)` operation.
3. You index into it to remove a stored value: `O(n)` operation.

In each step of the iteration from 1. above, you perform an O(n) operation two times. This is `2n * O(n)` which is equivalent to `O(n^2)`.

To remove from a linked list in `O(n)` time, you need to use its internal iterator mechanism to iterate over it, and to `iterator.remove()` items from it if they match your criteria.

### `ArarayList`

For the array-based list, the problem is that the remove operation is an `O(n)` operation: the items on the right of the removed element need to be moved over to the left. Going from the right-hand side *doesn't solve anything* because stored values still need to be moved to the left if you remove something on the far left-hand side of the array. Breakdown:

1. You iterate over the size of the list: `n` steps => `O(n)` operation.
2. You index into it to get a stored value: `O(1)` operation.
3. You remove a stored value: `O(n)` operation.

Which gives you `O(n^2)` performance.

You *cannot* remove elements from an `ArrayList` without having this sort of performance due to the remove operation being `O(n)` (unless the array is sorted and copying a portion of array is considered an `O(n)` operation).

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry...
So the best way to do it is to use an ArrayList?
What complexity do I have then? O(n)? and when using a LinkedList O(n^2) , am I right?

Comment: Oh no, I have a mistake in my calculation, one sec.

Comment: Thank you so much, it's very clear, so the performance is much better with an arraylist?

Comment: What's the entire complexity of algorithm 1?

Comment: The overall, practical performance is going to be better with the `ArrayList`. But the _Big-O_ algorithm complexity *is the same for both cases*, `O(n^2)`!

Comment: I perform 3 times an O(n) operation with LinkedList(1. 2. and 3.). Why isn't the complexity O(n^3)?

Comment: Because they multiply if and only if, one operation is performed *for each step* of the other operation. If the two operations happen independently, they just add up. And that doesn't make a difference for _Big-O_ notation (that is, `O(2n) == O(n)`).

Comment: In the `LinkedList` case, the `O(n)` look-up operation is completed by the time the `O(n)` remove operation is performed. But they both are performed *for each step* of the iteration in the loop.

Answer (score 0):

If `sortedList` is an instance of `LinkedList`, then the second algorithm has `O(n^2)` complexity due to `linkedlist.get(i)` has complexity `O(n)`.

Comment: Yes sorry, sortedList has to be LinkedList